# How to hide or keep bottom navigation down when keyboard appears while letting texteditor toolbar to move up and down?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a bottom navigation view and a texteditor toolbar which appears on top of bottom navigation.I want that when an edittext is clicked and keyboard pops up, bottom navigation hide and only toolbar moves with the keyboard.

I have tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` but it allow both bottomnavigation and toolbar to move. I've also tried using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`,however, both toolbar and navigation stop appearin on top of keyboard.

Here is my activity layout file:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- top toolbar -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rellayout1">

            <include layout="@layout/layout_top_tabs"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <!--middle section body -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rellayout2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rellayout1">

            <include layout="@layout/layout_centre_viewpager"/>

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment"
                android:name="com.Write.TitleFrag"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_title" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment2"
                android:name="com.Write.BodyFrag"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fragment"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_body" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- bottom navigation -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/WriteBottomNav">

            <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation_view"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

fragment2 contains editor and toolbar.
Here is fragment2 layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <com.github.irshulx.Editor
                android:id="@+id/editor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:focusedByDefault="true"
                android:paddingBottom="100dp"
                app:placeholder="Start writing here..."
                app:render_type="Editor">

            </com.github.irshulx.Editor>
        </ScrollView>


        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/toolsbottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#e6e6e6"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <include layout="@layout/write_toolbar_editor" />


        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no reliable way to tell when a keyboard is showing/shown, there's no reliable way to do this.  Neither input mode options know anything about navigation, there's no built in way to do this.  And there's no way to get notified when a soft keyboard appears.  Your best option is to not need this functionality.